# Is possible to use heap_trace_init_standalone() on arduino framework with esp32?

Tags: esp32

I need to trace memory leak but I can't find a way.
on IDF you can use heap_trace_init_standalone but there is not present on arduino framework.

Answer (score 1):

If you add `#include <esp_heap_trace.h>` (and define `CONFIG_HEAP_TRACING`) at the top of your sketch, the method should be available.

It is defined in `esp32\tools\sdk\esp32\include\heap\include\esp_heap_trace.h`